# I can't insert access application

Tags: sharepoint-addin

When i try to insert access aplication to my sharepoint 2013 site - it start to add but in the middle i get error "Sorry, there was a problem when adding the app. Click to try again" and it doesn't work
why?
thanks in advanced
Limor

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have configured/enable Access Services in SharePoint 2013

1. Install and configure SQL Server 2012 Enterprise software, because an Access app stores its data in a separate SQL Server back-end database.
2. Configure SharePoint Server 2013 for apps for SharePoint, because an Access app is an app for SharePoint.
3. Configure Access Services for Access apps so that Access Services can successfully run Access apps.
4. Create a dedicated SharePoint site collection for Access apps, because each Access app requires its own subsite.